# Are these overloads necessary?

Tags: c++, overloading

I have to write a library which contains a function that takes two strings parameters:

```
void foo(const std::string& arg1, const std::string& arg2);
```

My library is going to be used by some people that don't like C++ and are only used to `const char*`.

To satisfy their likes, I changed the prototype:

```
void foo(const char* arg1, const char* arg2);
```

And made my first version a simple inline call:

```
inline void foo(const std::string& arg1, const std::string& arg2)
{
  foo(arg1.c_str(), arg2.c_str());
}
```

Of course, thanks to the `std::string` constructors, it would have worked almost the same way with just the first version. Writing this overload just avoids instanciating useless `std::string` in the case someone passes only `const char*`.

But now I wonder: is this overload really necessary or is it just premature optimization ?

Also, I'm feeling like this is somehow incomplete: should I write also `void foo(const char* arg1, const std::string& arg2)` and `void foo(const std::string& arg1, const char* arg2)` overloads ? What if I have 3, 4 or more (`n`) parameters ? Should I write 2<sup>n</sup> overloads ?

In short, have you ever faced a similar situation ? What choices did you made and why ?

Thank you.

Comment: Encouraging the use of `const char*` strings by providing such an overload could actually be seen as a form of pessimization, when you consider the algorithmic benefits a proper string type can sometimes provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO it's reasonable to have two overloads to handle two different programming styles that co-exist within your organization.

Technically it's not *just* an optimization:

1. the `const char*` can be `extern "C"`, so might be useful for bindings from other languages, or even from other C++ code across a dll boundary with incompatible standard library implementation.
2. the conversion to `std::string` can throw `bad_alloc`, so if it cannot otherwise fail then the `const char*` version is useful if you have a C-style string and want to use it in a nothrow context.

Also beware that in principle `c_str()` can throw `bad_alloc`, but I doubt that any implementations actually do.

2<sup>n</sup> overloads doesn't seem worthwhile to me - if someone is mixing `string` and `char*` then it's not just a programming style difference, they're actually using mixed formats for some reason. Since they're using both already, they can convert for themselves.

This all assumes that the function is simple enough that you're happy to implement the actual work with `const char*` parameters. If the implementation based on `string` would be significantly simpler (for example if it takes significant code to make it exception-safe otherwise), then that probably wins over efficiency anyway, so don't provide any overloads, let their `const char*` convert to `string`.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you want to work with C++ (and not in C), the second one seems unneccessary, if you've this:

```
void foo(const std::string& arg1, const std::string& arg2);
```

You can call this with all combinations of `std::string` and `char*` as:

```
char *ca, *cb;
std::string sa, sb;
//...
foo(ca,cb); //char*, char*
foo(sa,cb); //std:string, char*
foo(sa,sb); //std::string, std::string
foo(ca,sb); //char*, std::string
```

Comment: Of course it works. But does it have a performance impact ? After all, instantiating a `std::string` just to call `c_str()` in the function body seems useless. Shouldn't I take care of this issue ?

Comment: @iammilind: What does that prove? If you **use** *uninitialized* variable, then its undefined behaviour in both cases. Its *good* that you got runtime error in case of `std::string`, but (unfortunately) you're NOT getting any error in case of `char*` but nevertheless its UB : http://www.ideone.com/Ki6Ex

Comment: @ereOn: I would say not, the caller should take care of the issue. If they care about performance, they can observe that their call with `const char*` and `string` results in an unnecessary conversion, and the fix is easy - call `c_str` on their second argument.

Comment: I know it's a bad behavior. But for the case of `const char*` we can have null check. See this example is about initialized pointer: http://www.ideone.com/02PTL

Answer (score 1):

If `const char * text` is never null, you could use `string`, because it has implictit constructor, so `string` class version could be enough. In other hand: if `const char * text` could be null, it generates runtime error.

One more thing: on DLL interface STL is not really good option. So if the function is part of a DLL interface, you may use C style strings.

I may do it in that way:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void foo( const string arg0, const string arg1 )
extern "C" _declspec( dllexport ) void foo( const char * arg0, const char * arg1 )
{
  string string_arg0, string_arg1;
  if ( arg0 != 0 )
    string_arg0 = arg0;
  if ( arg1 != 0 )
    string_arg1 = arg1;
  foo(string_arg0, string_arg1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your present approach is correct. Where you overload for `const char*` and provide a wrapper which also serves `std::string`.

If your colleagues are going to use C-style character pointer than it's better to do that way (present way). See following case;

```
char *p = 0;
foo(p);

void foo (const string &s)
{  // runtime error
}
```

[Demo](http://www.ideone.com/02PTL). As you can see that character pointers may not go well always with `std::string`; so why to take chance. Even though people may not do such coding; still you should avoid such potential hazards for long time maintainability.

Inside the function you can always choose to have `std::string` from `const char*` and write your algorithm.

Comment: Chances are, those situations where the `std::string` constructor would fail will also cause the underlying function to fail.  In the remaining situations where you get lucky and don't error out, perhaps you've just caught a bug a little earlier than you might have otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

In that case,  you could probably just have the (const char*,const char*) and ask everyone using std::string to use c_str().  That way there won't be any memory allocation overhead,  only the extra c_str() that people will have to code up.

Answer (score 0):

> My library is going to be used by some people that don't like C++ and
>   are only used to const char*.

Tell them to man up and learn the language that their compiler compiles. You take `std::string`, because that's how to do it in C++, and if they don't like it, then they can get a C compiler.

Comment: I would really tell things like that. But doing so would make me hated in the whole department. So not really an option ;)

Comment: @ereOn, also make sure that they don't know that you are the person behind "ereOn" alias name. :)